# What is the good practice to use graylog with tarantool?

Tags: tarantool

Currently our application uses tarantool provided log module, but was looking for a way to collect the logs into graylog. What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the graylog documentation, it could be used as a syslog server: https://www.graylog.org/post/how-to-use-graylog-as-a-syslog-server

And Tarantool supports writing to the syslog:
https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/latest/reference/configuration/#confval-log

All you need is to configure them in compliance:

```
box.cfg({log = 'syslog:server=127.0.0.1:1514'})
```